# Missing iptables file on directory /etc/init.d/ (Fedora 17)

Tags: iptables, firewall, fedora

Is the iptables file in Fedora 17 moved from `/etc/init.d/` to `/etc/sysconfig/`? I need do some patching to the iptables file to solve the firewall problem (Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle filter [FAILED]).

Comment: i think we need a bit of clarification on what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firewall in F17 has changed from iptables to FirewallD.

The init daemon was also replaced with systemd in F15, so you'll see many of the old init.d bash scripts are not there anymore.

Here's some places to get started:

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD
- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/7350/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-the-fedora17-firewall/

Comment: i thought the change from iptables to firewalld wasn't made until fedora 18 ...

Comment: Thx for the help. :)

Comment: Note you do not have to use firewalld, whereas systemd is non-optional, and that firewalld is just a (different) front-end to the kernel iptables anyway.  So you can uninstall firewalld (or disable the service) and use the old userspace iptables if you want (but you then have to create a service for it).  I believe the primary justification for firewalld is that it is simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

for IPv4: `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

for IPv6: `/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables`

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_edit_iptables_rules?rd=User_talk:Rforlot

Comment: Thx for the help. :)